# Jquery - Load Panolens file on Magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used 'PANOLENS' for interaction video and images.

http://pchen66.github.io/Panolens/examples/panorama_video.html

Maginic popup plugin:

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

I want to load Panolens interactive on lightbox window like youtube video loads. But, its not working as expected.

Any one please provide solution for this issue fix?

Thanks

**JS:**

```
var panorama, viewer, container;
var $interactiveEle = $('.interactive-holder').attr('data-interactiveurl');
container = document.querySelector('.interactive-holder');
panorama = new PANOLENS.VideoPanorama($interactiveEle, {autoplay: false});
viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({container: container});
viewer.add(panorama);

$('.open-interactive-link').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    src: '#interactive-popup',
    type: 'inline',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,
    fixedContentPos: false
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="open-interactive-link">Click here for interaction video</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is iframe aproach i guess. Create a seperate page with panolens content in it and recall this page with iframe.